# Create a method that can only take T as a parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I want to create a method that can only take a `double` as an argument.

If I write it like this:

```
public static void Foo(double d)
{
    // ...
}
```

Then we can call `Foo` with ints, floats, doubles, etc. Like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Foo(34); // int
    Foo(1.3454365F); // float
    Foo(34.12); // double
}
```

I tried to create a generic method that can only take a `double` as a parameter, like this:

```
public static void Foo<T>(T t) where T : double
{
    // ...
}
```

But type `double` can not be used as a constraint.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you pass an `int` to a method that receives a `double` it would be promoted to a `double`. Why is that a problem for you?

Comment: Actually, it is out of curiosity, we can achieve this in C++ by declaring a template function and deleting it.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to create a generic method? What's the added value? You constrain the T to one type, so could as well just use a normal method...

Comment: You want to disallow ints and such? Even if this were valid, you'd probably have the same problem. Perhaps you could ask how to disable implicit casts.

Comment: Yes, the topic of the question is closely related to implicit conversions.

Comment: @JHBonarius I thought of generic constraints to avoid conversions but later I thought that they also apply implicit conversions too. If we could say `where T : double`, we could be passing ints too.

Comment: I don't think C# has options to prevent this implicit conversion. Or options to require an explicit argument type.

Comment: What about overloads? `public static void Foo(int i) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }` ? Of course, this would fail at runtime. To have someting during designtime, I could imagine some code inspection to catch that.

Comment: @Fildor Thanks, overloads are a good idea, but failing at runtime is not desirable :/

Comment: If i understand you well, you want to pass different data types into `Foo` method.... Am i right?

Comment: @MaciejLos No, I want `Foo` to not take different data types and result in a compiler error. Example, if somebody tried to call the method with `int` parameter, it shouldn't accept it just because it is assignable to double (*implicit conversion*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can devise some types with implicit operators such that overload resolution will fail to decide a winner for some types but not others:

```cs
struct EvilDoubleWrapper
{
    public double Value { get; }

    public EvilDoubleWrapper(double value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator EvilDoubleWrapper(double value) => new EvilDoubleWrapper(value);

    public static implicit operator EvilDoubleWrapper(int value)
    {
        // If the program changes in such a way that this conversion is allowed to occur,
        // we should at a minimum raise an assertion
        Trace.Assert(true);
        return default;
    }
}

struct EvilOtherWrapper
{
    public static implicit operator EvilOtherWrapper(int value) => default;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo(1.23d); // Works
    Foo(1); // Error CS0121: The call is ambiguous
}

static void Foo(EvilDoubleWrapper d)
{
    // Use d.Value as your double
}

static void Foo(EvilOtherWrapper o)
{
    // Does nothing; only exists to fault the overload resolver
}
```

Neither of `EvilDoubleWrapper` nor `EvilOtherWrapper` is "better" than other other for overload resolution, and since there's an implicit conversion from `int` to both of them, overload resolution will fail. But there is only one implicit conversion from `double` to either of those, so overload resolution will successfully pick that one. Define implicit conversions for other built-in conversions that you want to forbid as well -- there's a rather small, closed set of such conversions listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/sk-sk/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions).